# Pass Quotes from a text box to external URL

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a simple VB.net app that has a text box that I pass to a URL for searching. So let's say I want to send this:
search "*ball"

So, my search will look for everything with ball after the *. The problem is, it strips the quotes when I send it.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://searchgames.local/search?game=" & TextBox1.Text)
```

How can I look for Quotes in my text box, then if they are there, pass them appropriately to the URL I am sending to. Below my code just makes sure they actually enter something into the textbox. As always, help is always appreciated.

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then ' If user does not enter any text
            MsgBox("Enter text to search on." & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Need search term to search on.")
            TextBox1.Focus() 'Set the cursor back to the text box
```

Comment: You need to URL encode the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a web app, you can use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) to properly escape the quotation mark characters.  Outside of a web application, MSDN recommends that you use [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx).  You could also use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx), but there seem to be [some problems](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/05/uriescapedatapath-and.html) with it.

So, for instance, you could do this:

```
Process.Start("https://searchgames.local/search?game=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text))
```

Or this:

```
Process.Start("https://searchgames.local/search?game=" & WebUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text))
```

Or this:

```
Process.Start("https://searchgames.local/search?game=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBox1.Text))
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! Thank you Steven! And I appreciate all of your input folks! Means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim url        as string = "https://searchgames.local/search?game=" & TextBox1.Text
Dim encodedurl as string = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(url)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(encodedurl)
```

Comment: You should only encode the query string, not the whole URL.